# Probability of choosing a certain random number

Tags: probability, infinity

Given person A chose a number out of the infinity set N, does the probability of person B choosing the same number defined?

Comment: This does not make any sense.  What probability distribution should we assume on $N$?  note:  "uniform" is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to choose a random number out of $\Bbb N$ such that all the numbers have equal chance to be chosen.  You can choose a random number with a probability distribution such that the sum of all the probabilities is $1$.  One such is $P(n)=2^{-n}$ (and $P(0)=0$ if you think $0 \in \Bbb N$).  If you know the probability distributions used by $A$ and $B$, the probability they pick the same number is well defined.  If $A$ uses the probability distribution $P_A(n)$ and $B$ uses $P_B*n)$ the chance they choose the same number is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_A(n)P_B(n)$. This is the same sum you would use for finite sets.   As the sum is monotonically increasing and bounded above by $1$, it converges nicely.

Comment: So for my question the answer is that such a probability is undefined right?

Comment: Once you define $P_A(n)$ and $P_B(n)$ it is well defined.  Without that definition it is not.  It is the same for finite sets, but often glossed over because there is the default assumption that "choose randomly" means equal probability for each option.  That doesn't work here.